# How to activate Dell Windows 10 cloned from another pc?

Tags: windows-10, dell-precision

understand that for windows 10 from oem the key is stored in the BIOS
"Dell keys are stored in the BIOS, as long as you use OEM install media, it will activate"

now i have 5 Dell pc of the same model and hardware configuration, i did the os configuration for 1 pc, cloned the image using marcium and restore over to the other 4 pc, but i realized the the windows can't be activated. Only if i use the oem media then the OS can be activated. is there any work around for this? cos it doesnt make sense for me to reconfigure all the windows account one by one for each pc, which involves alot of work as i made alot changes to the os policy settings too.

Comment: I'm not sure about business PCs but usually yes, the serial is stored in hardware in all new UEFI, not BIOS, machines, if Windows have been installed and validated once (there are PCs sold without OS). Typically they come with an OEM license that works if the same Windows version is later installed or reinstalled. It'll not activate different Windows versions and - I think - even language matters. You certainly can't activate a professional version with a stored home license.

Comment: OEM Windows licenses are not stored in a machine's BIOS, they are stored in the ACPI table, which while related (since the table is accessible within the firmware) it actually is not a machine's firmware.  Unlike previous versions of Windows, there is not a difference between a Retail and OEM Windows 10 image, Windows 10 will install and activate provided the license key and the image edition matches.  As for the activation status of multiple OEM machines, using a custom image, that can be automated with a script.  Your activation problems likely are connect to the image build process you used